# Обновление систем Ubuntu и Debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Я хочу полностью обновить рабочие сервера с Ubuntu 16.04 на 18.04 и с Debian 9 на 10 соответственно, у кого есть опыт, можете подсказать, как это лучше всего сделать и останутся ли текущие файлы конфигурации и программы на месте, в том числе установленные вручную?

В любом случае backup я сделал.

Comment: Останутся. Подробные инструкции по обновлению есть в официальных документациях соответствующих дистрибутивов

Comment: Тем не менее, у вас в любом случае должен быть план действий по установке и настройке всего сервера с нуля, а также тестовый сервер для экспериментов перед выполнением действий на реальном сервере. Если у вас всего этого нет, то вы не очень ответственный человек, вот

Comment: @andreymal спасибо.